# Can I replace my California emission engine with Federal emission engine?

Tags: engine, toyota, car, camry

So, recently I found out that my 2005 Toyota Camry 2.4 L (AZFE) California emission engine needs to be replaced. I found 2005 Camry engine  for $800, which turned out to be Federal emission engine. The seller told me that they have same motor so, it will work. California engine is very hard to find here so, should I go ahead and purchase the engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you going to be doing the replacement or are you going to be paying a mechanic to do it? Just remember, the seller wants you to buy something, so will tell you what you want to hear to get it sold. Obviously it wouldn't be CA complaint, but more than likely it would work. I don't know the differences with the two, but would assume there may be enough of a difference to where it might not work. This is really a non-answer for you, so leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Im paying mechanic to replace the engine. I have talked to him about both engines and he basically told me that he might be able to get it to work. I’m paying $1000 for the engine and I don’t want any issue along the way therefore, I’m little skeptical. I really want the engine to work.

Comment: If you are paying the mechanic to do the job, you should expect it to be done right (ie: running like it should when all is said and done). If you trust the mechanic, there should be little if anything to be worried about.

Comment: If the control systems (fuel, ecu etc) are from the Calif engine it should meet the emissions - CARB have the most exacting standards IIRC... But you should check.

Comment: Where are you? If you're in CA, even if the car runs well with a US-compliant engine, the car is unlikely to pass DMV's every-two-years required emissions test.

Comment: Concur with @David. Part of the CA emissions test is a visual inspection of the engine. If any CA-required equipment is missing, broken, or disconnected, the vehicle will fail...period. It doesn't matter if the tailpipe emissions themselves are ok, and most likely won't even be tested beyond the physical, visual inspection.

Comment: He's in Colorado.